# Convergence of $(1/n)^{1/n}$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a_n=(1/n)^{1/n}$. How to show that this sequence converges to 1?

Answer (score 2):

$a_n = e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln \frac{1}{n}}$.

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\ln \frac{1}{n} = 0$, hence $a_n \to 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Since for $x>0$, $\displaystyle (1+x)^n = 1 + x + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2+\cdots > 1 + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2$.

Hence $\displaystyle \bigg(1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\bigg)^n\geq 1 +\frac{n(n-1)} {2}\times\bigg(\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\bigg)^2> 2n-1 \geq n$, we have

$\displaystyle 1\leq n^{1/n} \leq 1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}$

Now the conclusion follows by letting $n\to \infty$.

Comment: How do you get from line 2 to line 3?

Comment: $(1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}})^n \geq n \geq 1 => 1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}} \geq n^{1/n} \geq 1^{1/n} = 1$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** Assume $a_n$ holds for $1 \leq x \leq n$. Now we show it holds for $a_{n+1}$.

$$a_{n+1} = \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$$

Let $p = n + 1$.
But this is equivalent to $$\sqrt[p]{\frac{1}{p}}$$

Now what is the limit as $p \to \infty$? It is monotone bounded, so it must exist.